# Regex to match a single character in String

Tags: java, javascript, regex

I want a regex to replace single character with a space (or delete them).

For example if I have:

```
" I have played u with no i and no j o o o o x w x x s"
```

It should return:

```
" have played with no and"
```

I have tried:

```
\s+\w{1}\s+
```

But when I use it i get:

```
" have played with no and no o o x x s"
```

I am missing something? I think it is related to some sort of  "overlapping matches".

Comment: Should it be "have played with no and no"? Is the first space intentional?

Comment: Show some code (how you're using this regex).

Comment: I plan to use it in Java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex works this way:

find `space` then one character then another `space`, and remove it. In this case spaces that surround one character can't be matched in test of another character like in case of

```
_a_b_c
^^^ -this part matches our pattern so it will be removed leaving 

b_c and now neither `b` or `c` is surrounded with spaces so they will not 
    be removed
```

To solve this problem just include in match one or more spaces (or start of string) and one character after it like `(^|\s+)\w`.
Also to make sure that after this character is at leas one space (or end of string) but to not include this spaces in match you can use [look-ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookahead) mechanism like `(?=\s+|$)`.

So in case of Java try

```
String newString = yourString.replaceAll("(^|\\s+)\\w(?=\\s+|$)","");
```

and in JavaScript

```
var replaced = text.replace(/(^|\s+)\w(?=\s+|$)/g,"")
```

BTW `\w` will match any character from `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` so you can change it to something like `[a-zA-Z]` if you want only letters.

Comment: I did not know of the Lookahead operator (never used). Thanks, that was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: (^|\s++)\w(?=\s++|$) ended up using this modification.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming the language is javascript (please check your tags). The problem I see is your regex includes the spaces, so if you have "aa b c", then it matches with " a ", but then c has no spaces before or after itself.

```
var text=" a bb c dd e f g tt"
var re=/\s*\b\w\b/g //If you're coding in Java, remove the g: "\\s*\\b\\w\\b"
text.replace(re,"") //" bb dd tt"
```

Comment: Actually this is simple... I was missing the word boundary operator.

Comment: @mfcabrera I would say that this may be even too simple because it will also accept `I` and `m` in `I'm`.

Comment: I don't know why someone down vote it... it is not as "straightforward" at it looks.